# Angular AsyncValidatorFn cause CPU and memory in high usage

Tags: angular

I have a table component can insert setting to create dynamic form, on each line is a formGroup and some input field can bind AsyncValidator.

I use it to build a table, on each line have some input field and an icon button can trigger an dialog to show details.
When I click the button, it will show a dialog with another table to show detail info (same component with previous table), so it also has some input field there and need to do async validate.

The problem is:

- If I bind a asyncValidator on the second table and open `F12` DevTools in **Chrome**/**Edge** browser, CPU & memory usage was in high usage and seems none stop
- But if I remove asyncValidator in setting, it will not bind asyncValidator, most time they worked fine and no CPU & memory high usage.
- The problem didn't happen in **Firefox** or not open `F12` Devtools in Chrome/Edge

I tried to search in Google, and I found some article, but seems not fit the problem

- [Memory leak when FormControlName created/destroyed few times · Issue #20007 · angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20007)

and my environment is

- @angular/cli version: 10.2.1

Does anyone meet the problem too?